# Javascript - When a string does not Match itself

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this Example 1:

```
myString = 'cdn.google.com/something.png';
console.log(myString.match(myString));
```

Everything works just fine, but when it comes to Example 2:

```
myString = 'cdn.google.com/something.png?231564';
console.log(myString.match(myString));
```

It returns the value of 'null'. I don't know what happened anymore.. I searched for the keywords 'a string does not Match itself' and found nothing. Can somebody help me? Thank you.

Comment: the `match` the first argument treat as regex(by parsing it)... in regex `?` has special meaning

Comment: Is there a way that I can make the match 'litteral'? Thank you

Comment: use `console.log(myString.indexOf(myString) > -1);`

Comment: For further information, you can check out some [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) on `match`

Comment: Trying now. Thank you first :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method would treat the argument as a regex(by parsing if not), where `.` and `?` has special meaning.

1. `.` matches any character (except for line terminators)
2. `?` Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed

So `.` wouldn't cause any problem since `.` can be used to match any character except line  but `?` would since it's using to match zero or one-time occurrence of any character.

For eg: `.png?23` => matches `.png23` or `.pn23`

---

From [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) :

> If a non-RegExp object obj is passed, it is implicitly converted to a RegExp by using new RegExp(obj).

---

It's better to use [`String#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) instead which returns the index in the string if found or returns `-1` if not found.

```
console.log(myString.indexOf(myString) > -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

match in Javascript compares a String against a RegEx. Luckily in your first example it works.

I guess you are looking for a method like [localCompare](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_localecompare.asp).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a same method that can replace 'replace' method like this localCompare method? thank you :)

Comment: Thank you very much bro!

Comment: I am unfortunately not aware of such a method for replace. You can try `str.split(search_string).join(replace_string)`. That should replace all occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

match() search the string using a regular expression pattern.

So

```
var s = "My String";
s.match(/Regex Here/);
```

will try to match s for given regular expression .

In your example:-

```
myString = 'cdn.google.com/something.png'; // It will be treated as regex
console.log(myString.match(myString));

myString = 'cdn.google.com/something.png?231564';  // It will be treated as regex , result differ because of ? 
console.log(myString.match(myString));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the argument to `match`, however if you do that you could just use `==` to compare the strings. This post contains a regex string escape function:

[How to escape regular expression in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593637/how-to-escape-regular-expression-in-javascript)

```
RegExp.quote = function(str) {
    return (str+'').replace(/[.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-]/g, "\\$&");
};
```

It can be used like this:

```
myString = 'cdn.google.com/something.png?231564';
console.log(myString.match(RegExp.quote
(myString)));
```

If you want to match any number after the question mark, you could do it like this:

```
myString = 'cdn.google.com/something.png?';
console.log((myString+"18193819").match(RegExp.quote
(myString) + '\\d+'));
```